# Contradiction about extending File Class C#

Tags: c#

I found contradiction in [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#extending-predefined-types) it says that you can extend it but in a lot of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311990/extend-file-class) threads I found that you can't extend it because it is static class. VS Community also did not let me compile my code because File is static type and it cannot be used as parameter.

Please explain me this part from documentation:

> Other examples might be to add common functionality to the System.String class, extend the data processing capabilities of the System.IO.File and System.IO.Stream objects, and System.Exception objects for specific error handling functionality. These types of use-cases are limited only by your imagination and good sense.

My test code:

- MyExtension class:

```
public static string ExtendFileClass(this File value)
{
    return value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It's correct that you cannot extend the type itself - because it's marked `sealed`, meaning it can't be subtyped. You can still define _extension methods_ for it - as in your test code.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen But extension methods on `File` are useless. You cannot create an instance of `File`, so you cannot call the extension method in a meaningful way. I would say that you cannot extend `File` in either sense of "extend". I suspect this might be a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: You are probably right, this is probably a mistake in the documentation.  Do note, however, that you can use extension methods to extend the poorly named `FileSystemInfo`, `DirectoryInfo`, and `FileInfo` classes.

Comment: @Zdeněk Jelínek, @LarsTech, you are right, my answer was not very helpful, the question was about the static class `File`, and nothing more. My answser is deleted :) Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write an extension method for `System.IO.File` like you did with `ExtendFileClass`. From [Referencing static class types]:[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#152242-referencing-static-class-types), it is specified that references to static classes are only permitted in a `typeof` expression, when you want to access a nested class of a static class, or in member-access expressions. It is not valid to use a static class anywhere else, e.g. as a parameter type.

Even if you can declare such a method, you cannot call this extension method in any meaningful way, because you cannot create an instance of `File` (and this is because `File` is a static class, as the linked post pointed out). All you can pass to the extension method would be `null`, and that's not very helpful.

I suspect that this is likely a mistake in the documentation. For reference, this particular part of the documentation was added by [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/17454). It seems like the `File` example here is also missed by the reviewer. I suspect the author might have meant [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-8.0) instead, which *is* a class that you can create instances of.

Side note: "extend" here means writing an extension method, not to be confused with the keyword `extends` in the context of [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance).